# How can I fix this 5-line python code?

Tags: python, numpy, graph

This code is running good on my local computer, but it gives error message on this online platform. The link is here: https://repl.it/GXl0/1

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: You probably can't. The platform doesn't seem to support plotting, it has nothing to do with your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyplot uses *TkAgg* as default backend, which you have in local but the platform doesn't. You need to explicitly give a working backend to the platform (in this case *Agg* works);

```
plt.switch_backend('Agg')
```

And to view the plot, you need to save it to a file. (To view the files you need to open project mode, where it connects to file server. You can do that by pressing "add a new file" button)

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.savefig('graph.png')
```

You can see the whole working code here https://repl.it/GXl0/2